# Best Practice schema for 1:1 relationship with multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

Currently, we have a 'messages' table with a column called "content_id" that creates a 1:1 relationship with anything a message can attach to, which are multiple other types of table data.

For instance, a message can be attached to another table row with a primary key that is an ID, and another message might be associated with another table's row with primary key of datatype varchar(36), or a uuid. There may be more tables to which a message could be assigned to one of their rows, with any other data type.

Lastly, a message can only be associated to a SINGLE ONE of any of those rows of various primary key data type.

Is there a better solution to this than a single column of varchar(36) in the messages table that can hold ints OR uuids?

If I use a join table for each relationship, I could put a UNIQUE index on the two columns that join them to make the same relationship. Is that architecture more efficient?

The DB is postgres, if that matters...

Comment: Is there a reason behind setting up one of the tables with an int ID and another with a UUID?  If they were both the same type, this type of relationship would be much easier to maintain.

Comment: One is populated by configuration scripts with unique uuids, the other is naturally generated auto incrementing IDs from a sequence. This whole problem disappears by not requiring the uuid to be a string, so let's assume for the question it needs to be... What's the best pracitice solution in a schema such as this?